# Sending SMS(s) through my company's software to ANDROID phone

Tags: java, android, sms

Can anyone point me the right direction as to how write a program that contacts and sends a SMS to the ANDROID phone?(ONLY asking for resources to help my coding)

Program Requirements:

1.When the SMS sending function is selected in my company's software,program will contact the ANDROID phone(connected through the USB) and the ANDROID will send the message to the target.

2.Program should also be able to delete the SMS from the sent messages or outbox folder in the ANDROID phone so that no trace of it is left behind.

I do not intend to have a GSM Modem ,only the ANDROID phone is connected through a USB for SMS sending.

If anyone can offer any words of advice,it'd be great.If not,please do not waste your time.All help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is "how to use basic coding"?  You just use it.  You start with the basics and improve from there.  I'd get a book on programming with Java, or perhaps an Android book.  Search this site for recommendations.  No-one's going to write you a tutorial, I'm afraid (I guess you could google for an existing one, though)

Comment: Seems like you wan't us to make your work. I don't event see what have you tried.

Comment: Your question needs basic correction. It should be `... software using ANDROID phone`. When you write `to ANDROID phone`, it means, the phone will receive the SMS

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great resource to help you get started with [Android Development and the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html).